# Explanation of $(x \notin A \setminus B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't understand  $(x \notin A \setminus B)$

Why is it not $$x \notin A \land x\in B$$ instead of $$x \notin A \lor x\in B$$

Comment: Here's a counterexample: take $A = \{ 0, 1 \}$ and $B = \{ 0 \}$. Then $A \setminus B = \{ 1 \}$, so $0 \not \in A \setminus B$ is true, but $1 \in A$, so $1 \not\in A \wedge 1 \in B$ is false. (The answers to this question provide answer why it *is* equivalent to the second expression.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $x$ is *not* a member of the set $A$ \ $B$.

Expressing that in words, this means that $x$ is not a member of the bunch of things that specifically lives in $A$, but not in $B$.

There are two ways in which this can happen. Either $x$ does not live in $A$ at all, or $x$ lives in $A$ but also lives in $B$.

Which is (after your edit) exactly what your last line says.

Comment: So both are true?

Comment: If $x\notin A\setminus B$ we could still have $x\in A\cap B$, so the first one is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

$x\notin A\setminus B \Longleftrightarrow \neg (x\in A\setminus B )\Longleftrightarrow \neg (x\in A\wedge x\notin B ) \Longleftrightarrow (x\notin A \vee x\in B)  $

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x \in A \backslash B$ is equivalent to $x \in A \: \wedge x \notin B$, hence $x \notin A\backslash B \Leftrightarrow \neg (x \in A \: \wedge \: x \notin B)$. By DeMorgan's Laws we conclude that $$x \notin A\backslash B \Leftrightarrow \neg (x \in A \: \wedge \: x \notin B) \Leftrightarrow (\neg(x \in A) \: \vee \: \neg(x \notin B)) \Leftrightarrow (x \notin A \: \vee \: x \in B).$$

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so

$ x \notin A\setminus B \Rightarrow x \notin A \cap B^c$ (by def. of $A \setminus B$).

$\Rightarrow x \in (A \cap B^c)^c$ (by negating the last).

$\Rightarrow  x \in A^c \cup B $ (by De Morgan Laws).

$\Rightarrow x \notin A \lor x \in B$.